# Saving and using TFIDF vectorizer for future examples, then leading to error with dimension

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I am training a Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier from Skilearn. I actually can now save that classifier using `from sklearn.externals import joblib`.

I want to now make a script to classify new examples. My only issue is taking new data, being strings and passing them onto the `classifier.predict( ... )` requires the data to be in vectorized form.

Before I would create a vectorizer, by the following:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, ngram_range=(1, 2),  stop_words='english', strip_accents='unicode', norm='l2',decode_error="ignore")
```

Now the way TFIDF works to vectorize, is it requires many many documents. But by creating a new vectorizer, I can't just pass it a single data structure to then classify it. I clearly need to save this vectorizer.

Really this comes to how to transform the data to the same form I trained the classifier on!?

Am I right in using the transform `vectorizer.transform(X_test_title)`

EDIT:

Seems I was right in my last comment above. However when now loading the classifier and vectorizer into my script, I seem to have issues passing the vectorized data to the classifier. Here is my function taking a title and document which are both clean strings:

```
def predict_function(title_data, document_data):
    data =  ((title + ' ') * number_repeat_title(title_data, document_data)) + document_data
    # requires a list
    data = [data, 'testing another element works']
    print data
    data_vector = vectorizer.transform(data)
    print data_vector # checking data is good!
    predicted = classifier.predict(data_vector) 
    return predicted
```

An example for calling this function is as follows:

```
predict_function('mr sponge bob square pants', 'SpongeBob SquarePants is an American animated television series created by marine biologist and animator Stephen Hillenburg for Nickelodeon. The series chronicles the adventures and endeavors of the title character and his various friends in the fictional underwater city of Bikini Bottom. The series' popularity has made it a media franchise, as well as Nickelodeon network's highest rated show, and the most distributed property of MTV Networks. The media franchise has generated $8 billion in merchandising revenue for Nickelodeon.')
```

I get an error, where I predict:

```
predicted = classifier.predict(data_vector)
```

giving....

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/naive_bayes.pyc in predict(self, X)
     61             Predicted target values for X
     62         """
---> 63         jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
     64         return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
     65 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/naive_bayes.pyc in _joint_log_likelihood(self, X)
    455         """Calculate the posterior log probability of the samples X"""
    456         X = atleast2d_or_csr(X)
--> 457         return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T)
    458                 + self.class_log_prior_)
    459 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/utils/extmath.pyc in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    189     from scipy import sparse
    190     if sparse.issparse(a) or sparse.issparse(b):
--> 191         ret = a * b
    192         if dense_output and hasattr(ret, "toarray"):
    193             ret = ret.toarray()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_572aaf0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/sparse/base.pyc in __mul__(self, other)
    337 
    338             if other.shape[0] != self.shape[1]:
--> 339                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
    340 
    341             result = self._mul_multivector(np.asarray(other))

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Comment: Could you please post the rest of your code? cleanTitle and cleanDocument aren't defined, and I have no idea what your data looks like.  At least post a sample of what that would be.  It's very hard to troubleshoot without all the methods/input samples.

Comment: The vectorizer's `fit` and `fit_transform` learn the vocabulary of their input data to determine the number of features in your problem. `transform` picks up only these features at test time.

Comment: @flyingmeatball I added in suggested info. I removed those functions as really they were just cleaning the strings passed in!

Comment: @larsmans yes I agree, but you can also save the vectorizer in memory and use at a later time, through using transform, as I have done!

Comment: How does that contradict what I said?

Comment: @larsmans I never said it did. I was simply stating that at a different time to test time you can use it

Comment: "Test time" in ML is a synonym of "prediction time". That may sound a bit confusing, but I think the idea is you "test" new samples against the model. (Either that, or it's just bad terminology, but you hear it from ML'ers all the time.)

Comment: I understand what you mean. I have tested the classifier to obtain accuracy, prediction, f scores etc. Now I am using it on new data going forward

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the scikit-learn documentation found here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html)
I believe you are correct.

The training data in the scikit-learn example is vectorized as follows:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                             stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)
```

This means the vectorizer will now remember the TFxIDF weightings.

These weightings are then applied to the test data with the following line of code:

```
X_test = vectorizer.transform(data_test.data)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just did this and now the data is vectorized, but the classifier is having issues! Will edit post!